# Issue passing parameters to a COBOL program using JCL PARM= on the EXEC statement

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

I wrote this simple code to print the parameter that I am passing through my JCL, why does it not print the parameter?

The code:

```
       CBL APOST                                  
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                   
       PROGRAM-ID. GETAPIT.                       
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                      
       CONFIGURATION SECTION.                     
       DATA DIVISION.                             
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                   
       LINKAGE SECTION.                           
       01   PARM-BUFFER.                          
            05 PARM-LENGTH   PIC S9(4) COMP.      
            05 PARM-DATA.                         
               10 numb       PIC X(6).            
               10 filler     PIC X(250).          
       PROCEDURE DIVISION using PARM-BUFFER.      
       MAINLINE SECTION.                          
           DISPLAY "NUMB:   " numb of PARM-DATA.  
       MAINLINE-EXIT.                             
          GOBACK.
```

```
//MVSSYNSQ JOB (3911),'&SYSUID',CLASS=F,MSGCLASS=R,NOTIFY=&SYSUID  
/*JOBPARM R=51,L=100                                               
//*                                                                
//GETAPI1  EXEC PGM=GETAPIT,PARM='000100'                          
//STEPLIB  DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=MVJE.ZCONN.LOADLIB                    
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=*
```

```
OUTPUT:
********************************* TOP OF DATA

NUMB:
```

Comment: How does your JCL look like, what does the program do (maybe you see no output at all)?

Comment: Only print the parameter that i am passing                            STEP EXEC PGM,PARM='000100'

Comment: I see output e.g displaying something

Comment: @Sherbel Nasra  - do you have a //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*  statement for the output to write to?

Comment: yes sure i have

Comment: Can you provide your JCL and your output, please?

Comment: It is interesting to read "I have JCL" and "I see output" - but if you don't show these we have only guessing instead of a definitive way to answer. Add the missing information to your question and we're likely able to provide an answer...

Comment: @Simon Sobisch added above in the description.

Comment: Is this output really from this program run with this JCL? Seems unlikely to me, because your output shows that a DISPLAY statement wrote *NUMB:* but nothing thereafter. Either you ran a JCL without ```PARM=```, or with ```PARM=""```, or a different version of the code which only has ```DISPLAY "NUMB:"```

Comment: Not correct , I did that 1000 times

Comment: Would you mind changing the ```DISPLAY``` statement in your program to display some more text behind the ```numb of PARM-DATA```, recompile, run, and show the output? Additionally, while looking at the output (in SDSF, I guess?) issue ```HEX ON``` on the SDSF command line. Then show the part which shows the result from the display statement.

Comment: As I don't know about the  pretty printing of `COMP` fields in that environment: you may want to add another `77 num-disp PIC 9(04).` and do `MOVE numb TO num-disp`, then `DISPLAY "NUMB: " num-disp`

Comment: @Simon Sobisch: ```numb``` is a character field defined as ```PIC X(6)```. You mixed this up with field ```PARM-LENGTH```. But even this field would be displayed as readable number in character format (except when negative). From the IBM Enterprise Cobol manual, section "DISPLAY" statement: *If identifier-1 is a binary, internal decimal, or internal floating-point data
item, identifier-1 is converted automatically to external format as follows:
v Binary and internal decimal items are converted to zoned decimal.
Negative signed values cause a low-order sign overpunch.*.

Comment: What is the output of `DISPLAY "PARM (" PARM-LENGTH "): " numb`?

Comment: The issue solved because the compiler option include CICS option, if I remove that I get the parameters correctly. the translator inserts EIB parameters to the parameters list, which screw up all the parameter list.

Comment: Good to know that this is solved. Please answer your own question as this perfectly matches SO's Q+A and if possible accept it as "answer that worked for me". When providing some background , possibly including where the compiler option was specified in, it can help the next time someone looks for this or a similar issue,

Answer (score 0):

it's worked with me when I compiled the COBOL program without the CICS integrator option.

Answer (score 0):

Used your test program with another DISPLAY to print the length of the parameter.

```
CBL APOST                                 
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                 
 PROGRAM-ID. GETAPIT.                     
 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                    
 CONFIGURATION SECTION.                   
 DATA DIVISION.                           
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                 
 LINKAGE SECTION.                         
 01   PARM-BUFFER.                        
      05 PARM-LENGTH   PIC S9(4) COMP.    
      05 PARM-DATA.                       
         10 numb       PIC X(6).          
         10 filler     PIC X(250).        
 PROCEDURE DIVISION using PARM-BUFFER.    
 MAINLINE SECTION.                        
     DISPLAY "LENGTH: " PARM-LENGTH.      
     DISPLAY "NUMB:   " numb of PARM-DATA.
 MAINLINE-EXIT.                           
          GOBACK.
```

With a parm of PARM='12345' I get this output.

> LENGTH: 0005
> NUMB:   12345

Note, I used a `SYSOUT` as opposed to `SYSPRINT` DD statement which is what you had in your JCL.

`//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*`

From what I could gather DISPLAY defaults to `STDOUT` which would be `SYSOUT` in `JCL`.

One other comment about `DISPLAY` from a [z/OS COBOL Programming Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/tasks/tpbeg16a.htm)

> To write data to the system logical output device, either omit the
> UPON clause or use the UPON clause with destination SYSOUT.
>
> Display "Hello" upon sysout.Copy code The output is directed to the
> ddname that you specify in the OUTDD compiler option. You can specify
> a file in the hierarchical file system with this ddname.
>
> If the OUTDD ddname is not allocated and you are not running in the
> z/OS UNIX environment, a default DD of SYSOUT=* is allocated. If the
> OUTDD ddname is not allocated and you are running in the z/OS UNIX
> environment, the _IGZ_SYSOUT environment variable is used as follows:
>
> Undefined or set to stdout Output is routed to stdout (file descriptor
> 1). Set to stderr Output is routed to stderr (file descriptor 2).
> Otherwise (set to something other than stdout or stderr) The DISPLAY
> statement fails; a severity-3 Language Environment condition is
> raised. When DISPLAY output is routed to stdout or stderr, the output
> is not subdivided into records. The output is written as a single
> stream of characters without line breaks.
>
> If OUTDD and the Language Environment runtime option MSGFILE specify
> the same ddname, both DISPLAY output and Language Environment runtime
> diagnostics are routed to the Language Environment message file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the JCL statement from //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=* to //SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*

OR, if you cannot change the JCL then recompile the COBOL program with the option OUTDD(SYSPRINT).

As a reference, see following documents:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=options-outdd
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=data-displaying-values-screen-in-file-display